# Cron job to edit PHP files daily

Tags: php, automation, cron, yaml

Good evening everyone.

I have managed to run PHP scripts on my server that allow me to extract the M3U8 files from a specific website. However, I've encountered an issue regarding those scripts: the page they're stored in has dynamic URLs that change every single day so, unfortunately, my scripts stop working after a day, so I know there are two ways to solve the problem:

1 - Looking up that page everyday and change the URLs to scrape from manually and individually, which would be insane because it would mean taking time in a daily basis to do so.

2 - Setting up a cron job that extracts the "variable" part of those dynamic URLs and overwrites the PHP scripts every 24 hours in order for them to work properly.

The worst part is, I don't even know where to start since I'm not familiar with cron jobs. I really couldn't try anything apart from messing with a few YAML and PHP files, with no results.

In case it could help, all my PHP scripts have the same structure, with this being the part the cron job should modify every day:

```
EXAMPLE.php

<?php

$url = "https://randomlivestreampage.xyz/1234/vid?ch=example";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

(in this case, ***1234*** would be the specific part that has to be updated)

Is there any way to set up a cron job to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should make the `1234` part a command-line parameter. Then you can use the same script for all the jobs. See [`$argv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Comment: Why can't the PHP script itself scrape the website to get the variable part?

Comment: Thank you @Barmar! It took me a while to find out how to do it, but I made a few other scripts to get that variable and then I made an array joining the constant parts and the variable part. I hope that the lines I added to the code work!